# iOS - [NSConcreteValue doubleValue] crash (animation?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-animation, uiviewanimation

Hi there is a crash in my application that I am unable to figure out. I believe it has to do with animation. I don't know where the crash is happening so I have included where I think it happens, and a few methods that animation happens in.

In UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass:

```
#define kTransformScale CATransform3DMakeScale(.8, .8, 1)
#define kTransformAngle M_PI

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    if ([self.insertIndexPaths containsObject:itemIndexPath])
    {
        // only change attributes on inserted cells
        if (!attributes)
        {
            attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
        }

        attributes.alpha = 0.0;

        if([_coordinator isCorporateTile:itemIndexPath.item])
        {
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation([self collectionViewContentSize].width, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(kTransformScale, kTransformAngle, 0, 1, 0);
        }
    }

    return attributes;

}
```

---

```
+ (CABasicAnimation *)animationFromTransformation:(CATransform3D)fromTransformation
                                 toTransformation:(CATransform3D)toTransformation
                                   timingFunction:(CAMediaTimingFunction *)timingFunction
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:fromTransformation];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:toTransformation];
    animation.timingFunction = timingFunction;
    animation.duration = duration;

    return animation;
}
```

---

```
- (void)animateToTransform:(CATransform3D)toTransform
            timingFunction:(CAMediaTimingFunction *)timingFunction
                  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                alterModel:(BOOL)alterModel
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:[(CALayer *)[self presentationLayer] transform]];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:toTransform];
    animation.timingFunction = timingFunction;
    animation.duration = duration;

    if (alterModel)
    {
        self.transform = toTransform;
    }

    [self addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];
}
```

---

```
2334 |   01:19:46:727 |$ ERROR: Uncaught Exception: -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1807fce0
2335 |  *01:19:46:727 |(
2336 |   00:00:00:000 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e343e9b <redacted> + 154
2337 |   00:00:00:001 |  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x389ed6c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2338 |   00:00:00:002 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e3477b7 <redacted> + 202
2339 |   00:00:00:003 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e3460af <redacted> + 706
2340 |   00:00:00:004 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e294dc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
2341 |   00:00:00:005 |  QuartzCore                          0x30833ae5 <redacted> + 40
2342 |   00:00:00:006 |  UIKit                               0x30ced03b <redacted> + 226
2343 |   00:00:00:007 |  UIKit                               0x30cececb <redacted> + 14
2344 |   00:00:00:008 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e28c803 <redacted> + 50
2345 |   00:00:00:009 |  CoreFoundation                      0x2e28621d <redacted> + 220
2346 |   00:00:00:010 | UIKit                               0x30af731f <redacted> + 526
2347 |   00:00:00:011 | UIKit                               0x30accd79 <redacted> + 196
2348 |   00:00:00:012 | UIKit                               0x30acb569 <redacted> + 7116
2349 |   00:00:00:013 | CoreFoundation                      0x2e30ef1f <redacted> + 14
2350 |   00:00:00:014 | CoreFoundation                      0x2e30e3e7 <redacted> + 206
2351 |   00:00:00:015 | CoreFoundation                      0x2e30cbd7 <redacted> + 630
2352 |   00:00:00:016 | CoreFoundation                      0x2e277471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
2353 |   00:00:00:017 | CoreFoundation                      0x2e277253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
2354 |   00:00:00:018 | GraphicsServices                    0x32f7e2eb GSEventRunModal + 138
2355 |   00:00:00:019 | UIKit                               0x30b2c845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
2356 |   00:00:00:020 | nukonize.dylib                      0x0052df0f nukona_UIApplicationMain + 358
2357 |   00:00:00:021 | BrokerPresent                       0x00086c2b main + 70
2358 |   00:00:00:022 | libdyld.dylib                       0x38ee6ab7 <redacted> + 2
2359 |  *00:00:00:022 |)
```

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint to pinpoint the offending line?

Comment: No, it happens randomly and I haven't been able to reproduce it. The log is what I have to go by.

Comment: What's the "redacted" for?

Comment: @matt I think it's a no symbolicated crash log: http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/2284-ios6-crash-logs

Comment: @Rivera Without symbolication, surely nothing can be done...

Comment: Looks like you ended up with an NSConcreteValue where you expected an NSNumber.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to specify fromValue?

Comment: The code I posted is from a third party library PKRevealController so I'm not sure whether the fromValue is needed or not.

Comment: I don't know about animations yet (but it's quite interesting and I'm gonna try soon), but could it be, that at some point `[self presentationLayer]` is set to an object different class, and so the cast with `(CALayer *)` doesn't work as expected, and so the `NSValue` can't work properly?